# String array manipulation

Tags: java, arrays

The array is created with 25 possible elements, and is only populated if the user enters a string to place into the array.  All of the code with the exception of the body inside the methods was [provided](https://ideone.com/7HtN8A).

As far as I know

- the `addFlower` method is working properly
- the `sortFlowers` method is working properly
- the `searchFlowers` method is working properly

The `removeFlower` method is completely confusing me.  Any help on a direction to go here would be greatly appreciated.

The `displayFlowers` method is the current problem.

The output I am getting is at the bottom.  I can't figure out why the output is like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment01Driver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Assignment01Driver();
    }

    // This will act as our program switchboard
    public Assignment01Driver() 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] flowerPack = new String[25];

        System.out.println("Welcome to my flower pack interface.");
        System.out.println("Please select a number from the options below");
        System.out.println("");

        while (true) 
        {
            // Give the user a list of their options
            System.out.println("1: Add an item to the pack.");
            System.out.println("2: Remove an item from the pack.");
            System.out.println("3: Sort the contents of the pack.");
            System.out.println("4: Search for a flower.");
            System.out.println("5: Display the flowers in the pack.");
            System.out.println("0: Exit the flower pack interfact.");

            // Get the user input
            int userChoice = input.nextInt();           

            switch (userChoice) 
            {
            case 1:
                addFlower(flowerPack);
                break;
            case 2:
                removeFlower(flowerPack);
                break;
            case 3:
                sortFlowers(flowerPack);
                break;
            case 4:
                searchFlowers(flowerPack);
                break;
            case 5:
                displayFlowers(flowerPack);
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Thank you for using the flower pack interface. See you again soon!");
                System.exit(0);
            }           
        }       
    }

    private void addFlower(String flowerPack[]) 
    {
        String str;
        int index = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What type of flower are you adding?");
        str = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length; i++) 
        {
            if (flowerPack[i] != null) 
            {
                index++;
                if (index == flowerPack.length) 
                {
                    System.out.println("The pack is full");
                }
            } else 
            {
                flowerPack[i] = str;
                System.out.println("Added: " + str + " at index " + i);
                break;
            }
        }       
    }

    private void removeFlower(String flowerPack[]) 
    {
        String flr;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What flower do you want to remove?");
        flr = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            if (flr.equalsIgnoreCase(flowerPack[i])) 
            {
                flowerPack[i] = flowerPack[i + 1];
            }
        }       
    }

    private void sortFlowers(String flowerPack[]) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length; i++) 
        {
            String currentMin = flowerPack[i];
            int currentMinIndex = i;

            for (int j = i; j < flowerPack.length; j++) 
            {
                if (flowerPack[j] != null) 
                {
                    if (currentMin.compareToIgnoreCase(flowerPack[j]) > 0) 
                    {
                        currentMin = flowerPack[j];
                        currentMinIndex = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (currentMinIndex != i) {
                flowerPack[currentMinIndex] = flowerPack[i];
                flowerPack[i] = currentMin;
            }
        }
    }   

    private void searchFlowers(String flowerPack[]) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        System.out.println("What flower would you like to search for?");
        str = input.nextLine();     
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length; i++) {
            if (flowerPack[i] != null && flowerPack[i].equalsIgnoreCase(str)) 
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) 
        {
            System.out.println("We found your flower.");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("That flower was not found.");
        }       
    }

    private void displayFlowers(String flowerPack[]) 
    {
        sortFlowers(flowerPack); 
        int count = 1;                          
        for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length - 1; i++) 
        {       
            if (flowerPack[i] != null)
            {           
                if (flowerPack[i].equalsIgnoreCase(flowerPack[i+1]))
                {               
                    count++;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                if (flowerPack[i] == null)
                {
                    break;  
                }
            }
        System.out.println(flowerPack[i] + "s - " + count);
        count = 1;
        }
    }
}


Input:
1 <enter>, "Lilly" <enter"
1 <enter>, "Lilly" <enter>
1 <enter>, "Rose" <enter>
5 <enter>

Output:
Lillys - 2
Lillys - 1
Roses - 1
```

Comment: "I can't figure out why the output is like this." What do you want it to look like?

Comment: "Any help on a direction to go here would be greatly appreciated." What do you want it to do?

Comment: Lillys - 2         Roses - 1

Comment: The method asks the user for a String.  I need the method to search the array for that String,  if found, remove the string, then shift all elements left, so there is no null in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `i` outside of the for loop

```
int count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length - 1; i++) 
{       
    if (flowerPack[i] != null)
    {           
        if (flowerPack[i].equalsIgnoreCase(flowerPack[i+1]))
        {               
            count++;
        }   
        else
        {
            System.out.println(flowerPack[i] + "s - " + count);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (flowerPack[i] == null)
        {
            break;  
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Initializing i outside the loop and moving the print statement causes the output to change to "nulls - 2'

Comment: I have edited the solution. It should work now.

Comment: Aha!!  So moving the print statement into an 'else' and adding the counter there, fixed it  :)

Comment: After there is no more flowers of one type you have to display how many flowers it counted so far and reset the counter to 1. Easy! Have fun with Java!

Answer (score 0):

Removing a flower from the pack should go like this:

```
private void removeFlower(String flowerPack[]) 
{
    String flr;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What flower do you want to remove?");
    flr = input.nextLine();

    boolean del=false;

    for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        if (flr.equalsIgnoreCase(flowerPack[i])) 
        {
            del = true;
        }

        if (del)
        {
            flowerPack[i] = flowerPack[i + 1];
        }

        if (flowerPack[i] == null) {
            break;
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are useless pieces of code in the answer of @Marek

You could shorten it with

```
int count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length -1 && flowerPack[i] != null; i++) 
{       
    if (flowerPack[i].equalsIgnoreCase(flowerPack[i+1]))
    {               
        count++;
    }   
    else
    {
        System.out.println(flowerPack[i] + "s - " + count);
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the length - 1 because I was running comparisons with [i + 1].  If the loop was checking the last element in the array, [i + 1] would cause an 'Out of bounds' error.